How do i make a word filter in pycord?
With my little knowledge on pycord, I tried to make a bot that deletes new messages with certain content but it did not work out.
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    if message == "test":
        await message.delete

I wanted it so if I said test in the chat it would delete the message

First thing, please put code in a code block. Python's indentation matters to the point where it's unreadable if you don't put it in a code block. Second, message is an object and not a string that you can test equivalence on. Therefore, try: message.content

I do not know your entire codebase, but here is an example code that should do what you asked for
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True  # noqa
bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)


class BannedWords(commands.Cog):
    BANNED_WORDS: list[str] = ["test"]

    def __init__(self, bot: discord.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message):
        if message.content in self.BANNED_WORDS:
            await message.delete()


bot.add_cog(BannedWords(bot))

bot.run("YOUR-DISCORD-TOKEN-HERE")

I am using a cog in order to have cleaner code.
I suspect that your issue comes from either

The fact that you forgot () after delete in your code.
The fact that you are comparing message and not message.content with "test"
The fact that that you don't have the message intent enabled. Intents in discord are like "permissions" of what your bot is allowed to do. To fix this, make sure that in your discord developer portal you enabled the message content intent like the picture:

Also, make sure that you enabled this intent in your code, like I did above:

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True  # noqa

bot = discord_extension.Bot(intents=intents)

Also, make sure that your bot has the permission to delete messages in your server.
Please let me know if something is unclear and you want more explanations.
